# I can't find the Save Buffers checkbox in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am trying to show the tiles as they are being rendered and another forum post said to uncheck the *Save Buffers* checkbox but I cannot find the checkbox

Comment: Never heard of that box. Blender defaults to showing the tiles, however I think if one uses CPU rendering they default to being very large (as is optimal). Tried searching the docs and found something that said it was in the Performance panel, but did not find more information. It may no longer exist. What exactly can you see?

Answer (score 5):

The *Save Buffers* checkbox is only available in Blender 2.9X in the *Cycles* render engine settings under *Render Properties > Performance > Final Render*. It is **not** available in Blender 3.0+ and onwards.

Also see bug report https://developer.blender.org/T87895

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the *Save Buffers* function or do you just want to see the tiles while rendering?

In older *Cycles* versions you had the tiles showing because rendering performance was better with smaller tiles like 16x16, 32x32 or 64x64 for CPU rendering and larger tiles like 128x128 or 256x256 for GPU rendering.

The recent *Cycles X* development got rid of this and usually renders the full frame at once. However, and this is why people sometimes wonder if there is something wrong when trying to render in 4k, under the *Performance* > *Memory* settings there is an option called *Use Tiling*, it's enabled by default and set to a *Tile Size* of 2048 pixels.

That's why in a standard format like 1920x1080 Blender renders full frames, but as soon as one of the image dimensions goes past 2048 pixels you will have tiling again (if you leave the option enabled).

So if your goal is just to see tiles while rendering, you can simply leave the option enabled and set a smaller tile size like 128 or 64 pixels. Presumably this will slow down the render, but who knows? Depending on your hardware there might be a setting that's better for your performance than the default.

[image: use tiling]